# Qualitative data comparison with multiple classes

Tags: r, statistics, comparison

Say you have a data organized on the following way: 3 populations of individuals (pop1, pop2, pop3), where each one of them were assessed by different categories (smoking, drinking, exercise, breakfast). All the factors evaluated are discrete values, where `smoking` represents cigarettes/day (values: `1-5`; `6-10`; `11-15`; `16-20`; `21-30`; `30+`), `drinking` represents alcohol consumption/week (values: `1-5`; `6-10`; `11-15`; `16-20`; `20+`), `exercise` represents how many days of physical activities/week (values: `1`; `2`; `3`; `4`; `5`; `6`; `7`), and finally `breakfast` represents whether the subject have breakfast on a regular basis (values `yes`, `no`).
Here is an example of the data frame:

```
> df
   Subject Population Smoking Drinking Exercising Breakfast
1        1       Pop2   11-15    16-20          6       Yes
2        2       Pop3     1-5     6-10          4        No
3        3       Pop1   11-15    16-20          6       Yes
4        4       Pop2    6-10     6-10          5        No
5        5       Pop2    6-10     6-10          6       Yes
6        6       Pop2   21-30     6-10          6        No
7        7       Pop1    6-10    16-20          4        No
8        8       Pop1     1-5    16-20          6       Yes
9        9       Pop3   11-15    16-20          1        No
10      10       Pop2   16-20      1-5          3        No
11      11       Pop3    6-10     6-10          4        No
12      12       Pop2  30plus    11-15          4       Yes
13      13       Pop2   11-15    11-15          1       Yes
14      14       Pop3   11-15     6-10          6        No
15      15       Pop1  30plus    16-20          1        No
16      16       Pop3   11-15   20plus          1        No
17      17       Pop2   11-15     6-10          2       Yes
18      18       Pop1   21-30    11-15          7       Yes
19      19       Pop2   16-20      1-5          2        No
20      20       Pop2   11-15    11-15          5       Yes
21      21       Pop3  30plus   20plus          4       Yes
22      22       Pop2  30plus     6-10          3       Yes
23      23       Pop1    6-10   20plus          5        No
24      24       Pop1   11-15     6-10          3       Yes
25      25       Pop1  30plus   20plus          4       Yes
26      26       Pop3   11-15     6-10          7       Yes
27      27       Pop1   21-30    11-15          5       Yes
28      28       Pop3   16-20   20plus          6        No
29      29       Pop2    6-10    11-15          4        No
30      30       Pop3    6-10     6-10          5       Yes
```

I would like to evaluate whether there is a difference in smoking, drinking, exercising and breakfast between the 3 populations. **What would be the most reliable test to apply here (chi-square, Fisher's, logistic regression)?**. Also, would you consider a uni- or multivariate approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about statistical analysis are better suited to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is specific to coding.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielO. I have just posted it there now.